# Does Windows require the EFI system partition to be the first partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning

According to several guides (including [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions) one by Microsoft) Windows 10 just needs

- an EFI system partition (ESP),
- a MSR partition (apparently for GPT stuff),
- a system/OS partition, and
- a recovery partition.

However, I couldn't find any definite statements on the partition numbers, their order and the free space between the partitions. So after experimenting a bit I found the following scenarios, all of which allow the system to install without any errors, but some of which won't let the system boot.

Here are the partitions I am going to use to describe the scenarios

- "ESP" will be a 500 MiB partition with type `EFI System Partition` (type code `ef00` or type GUID `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`), which is formatted FAT-32 (using `mkfs.vfat -F 32`)
- "MSR" will be a 16 MiB partition with type `Microsoft reserved` (type code `0c01` or type GUID `E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE`), which is unformatted
- "Win" will be a 32 GiB partition with type `Microsoft basic data` (type code `0700` or type GUID `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`), which is formatted NTFS (using `mkfs.ntfs --fast`)
- "WinRE" will be a 1 GiB partition with type `Microsoft basic data`, which is formatted NTFS (using `mkfs.ntfs --fast`)
- "Raw" will be an unformatted partition of unspecified size with type `Microsoft basic data`.

To describe the scenarios I'm gonna use strings such as `1:ESP, 2:MSR, 3:Win, 4:WinRE, [remaining]` where the numbers represent the partition number assigned with `gdisk` (on ArchLinux), the order of items in the string describes the physical on-disk order of partitions and free space, and the brackets describe free space (excluding the GPT header itself).

Here are the scenarios, where the installation succeeds (without any errors) and the system boots.

- `1:ESP, 2:MSR, 3:Win, 4:WinRE, [remaining]`
- `1:Win, 2:WinRE, 3:MSR, 4:ESP, [remaining]`
- `2:MSR, 1:ESP, 3:Win, 4:WinRE, [remaining]`
- `1:Win, 2:WinRE, 3:MSR, 5:ESP, [remaining]`

Here are the scenarios, where the installation succeeds (without any errors), but the system won't boot. All cases end in a blue screen with the error code `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.

- `2:MSR, 3:ESP, 4:Win, 5:WinRE, [remaining]`
- `[1 MiB], 2:Raw, 3:ESP, 4:MSR, 5:Raw, 6:Win, 7:WinRE, [remaining]`
- `[1 MiB], 3:ESP, 4:MSR, [32 GiB], 6:Win, 7:WinRE, [remaining]`
- `1:ESP, 2:MSR, 3:WinRE, 5:Win, [remaining]`

---

I tested all of those scenarios in VirtualBox, but I am fairly certain that this would happen on a physical machine as well (though I haven't got any spare machines lying around).

**My question now is, whether this is expected behavior?** I certainly wasn't able to find any documentation that would rule out all the failing scenarios as valid partition layouts. Maybe you guys know more.

I would also be interested, if someone can reproduce this behavior either in VirtualBox, or using other virtualization software, or on a physical machine.

Comment: Do you fully reinstall Windows for each layout, or do you manually update the EFI NVRAM data and the Windows BCD after each repartitioning, or do you just swap the partitions with no further changes?

Comment: @user1686 I full reinstall Windows (change layout, do all the `mkfs.*` commands completely cleaning all volumes, and then install Windows again).

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. It normally is, which is a very good idea because if you have to repair the partition, you know where it starts.

Comment: You would know anyway where the ESP starts, because it is the only partition with the type GUID `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the system wouldn't boot in scenario 2. If I partition the drive with the order "1:MSR, 2:ESP, 3:Recovery, 4:Windows, [free space]", it still boots.

Comment: Well, I'm gonna keep experimenting and updating my question :)

Comment: There may be two partitions with that GUID, just checked, it works, the one in efibootmgr nvram memory will be booted, so not necessary the first one. If you delete the second active ESP it will boot from the first immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after looking really hard at those scenarios (and experimenting even more) I came to the conclusion that

- the order of the partitions themselves doesn't seem to matter at all,
- the order of partition entries in the GPT seems to matter, sometimes,
- the order of each contiguous range of assigned GPT entries seems to be irrelevant.

My best guess is that the Windows bootloader, when booting the system, searches for the Windows partition by iterating the GPT entries from the beginning to the end terminating the search upon discovering an unassigned partition entry (type GUID `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`).

If this is true, then the Windows partition must be located within the first contiguous range of assigned GPT entries.